# Trying to find LCM(least common multiple) with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, lcm

My code is this:

```
num1 = int(input(": "))
num2 = int(input(": "))
list1 = []
x, z, y = 0, 0, 0
while x < 100:
    z += num1
    y += num2
    list1.append(z)
    list1.append(y)
    x += 1
for i in list1:
    if list1.count(i) > 1:
        print(i)
        break
```

It works fine but i wanted to change

```
while x < 100:
```

because it is sloppy to this:

```
num1 = int(input(": "))
num2 = int(input(": "))
list1 = []
x, z, y = 0, 0, 0
for i in list1:
  while list1.count(i) < 2:
    z += num1
    y += num2
    list1.append(z)
    list1.append(y)
    x += 1
else:
    print(i)
```

and `NameError: name 'i' is not defined` occurs.
I am e new member here and just started learning Python.
Any help?Thanks in advance!

Comment: With your current indentation `else` is part of your `for` loop, not your `while` loop. As list1 is empty variable i never gets assigned and thus raises the error you see when you try to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Common error. you just didn't indent the else. At least that solved the issue when I ran the code.
else:
print(i)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the 'i' undefined error is that you wrote the print(i) statement at the same level as the for loop. The i variable is only accessible to statements **inside** your for loop not outside it.

Also your code will not find the LCM because you made the mistake of calling a for loop on an empty list. If the list is empty the for loop won't even run once.

In order to streamline your code, I suggest doing away with lists entirely and using simple if-else statements and a while loop

Here's my approach -

```
num1 = int(input(": "))
num2 = int(input(": "))

greaterNum = None
LCM = None

if num1 > num2:
    greaterNum = num1
else:
    greaterNum = num2

while True:
    if((greaterNum%num1 == 0) and (greaterNum%num2 == 0)):
        LCM = greaterNum
        print(LCM)
        break
    else:
        greaterNum += 1
```